# Does the 'Greatest Hits' versions of Ps3 shares the same Save File as the original, black label version?

Tags: ps3

Does the 'Greatest Hits' versions of Ps3 shares the same Save File as the original, black label version? *For example, Final Fantasy XIII?* I'm not talking about the extras that have the DLCs or new content, but the ones that are different due to the version/color of the box. Can i continue playing on a regular/Greatest Hits version with the same save file, if both of the games are NTSC/PAL and from the same region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** 
Greatest Hits games are usually just Sony re-releasing the same game a few years later, they usually come with bug fixes and updates, but they will use the same file as the original as they are the same game.